# Index contains multiples value dataframe pivots

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, dataframe

I currently have data in the following format in a dataframe:

```
           metric__name  sample sample_date
0    ga:visitBounceRate     100  2012-11-13
1    ga:uniquePageviews      20  2012-11-13
2          ga:newVisits      19  2012-11-13
3             ga:visits      20  2012-11-13
4   ga:percentNewVisits      95  2012-11-13
5  ga:pageviewsPerVisit       1  2012-11-13
6          ga:pageviews      20  2012-11-13
7    ga:visitBounceRate      72  2012-11-14
8    ga:uniquePageviews      63  2012-11-14
9          ga:newVisits      39  2012-11-14
```

That being said, I am trying to break out the metric__name column into something like this.

```
                ga:visitBounceRate ga:uniquePageviews ga:newVisits     etc...
sample_date
2012-11-13                100                20                 19     etc...
```

I am doing the following to get my desired result.

```
df.pivot(index='sample_dates', columns='metric__name', values='samples')
```

All I keep getting is index contains multiple values which it indeed does, but why wouldn't it understand that there are similar and map them to the same line as I did in my desired output?

Comment: Isn't that "Transpose". Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you'd like?  Does `pivot` give the correct output or not?  If not, what is incorrect about it? Do you just want the values for 2012-11-13?

Comment: @TomAugspurger so i clearly say what the `pivot` is giving me index contains multiple values. I also listed what I would like as an ouput.

Comment: Is `df.pivot(index='sample_date', columns='metric__name', values='sample').ix['2012-11-13']` what you want? Your desired output doesn't make sense any other way.  I don't know what you mean buy "understand that [they] are similar and map them to the same line".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) (which doesn't throw this exception):

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table('sample', 'sample_date', 'metric__name')
Out[11]:
metric__name  ga:newVisits  ga:pageviews  ga:pageviewsPerVisit  ga:percentNewVisits  ga:uniquePageviews  ga:visitBounceRate  ga:visits
sample_date
2012-11-13              19            20                     1                   95                  20                 100         20
2012-11-14              39           NaN                   NaN                  NaN                  63                  72        NaN
```

It accepts an aggregation function (by default is mean):

> `aggfunc` : function, default `numpy.mean`, or list of functions
>        If list of functions passed, the resulting pivot table will have hierarchical columns
>        whose top level are the function names (inferred from the function objects themselves)

*Regarding the difference between the two, I think [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) just does **reshaping** (and throws an error if there is a problem), whereas [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations) offers more advanced functionality, aka "spreadsheet-style pivot tables".*

Comment: can you explain the difference between `pivot` and `pivot_table`?

Comment: I think it is purely that [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations) allows more advanced functionality, "spreadsheet-style pivot tables", wheras [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) just does *reshaping* (and throws an error if there is a problem).